# How can I make react's useEffect to stop rerender in an infinite loop even with a dependency specified?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a small CRUD fullstack app with react and mongodb and I have this problem where I use `useEffect` to make an axios get request to the server to get all of my todos. The problem is that `useEffect` does it's job but it also rerenders to infinity. This is my component:

```
export default function () {
    ...
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))._id;

    useEffect(() => {
        async function populateTodos () {
            try {
                const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/all-todos/${currentUser}`);
                setTodos(res.data);
            } catch (err) {
               if (err.response) {
                    console.log(err.response.data);
                    console.log(err.response.status);
                    console.log(err.response.headers);
               } else if (err.request) {
                   console.log(err.request);
               } else {
                   console.log('Error: ', err.message);
               }
            }
        }

        populateTodos();
    }, [todos]);

    console.log(todos);

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

So what I was expecting to happen is that that `console.log` to get printed only when the todos changes, like when I add a new todo and so on, but instead it gets printed forever.

Comment: Think about the flow of this: Run the effect when `todos` changes. Update the value of  `todo`'s within the effect.

Comment: Are you sure you want to run the effect when `todos` changes? Or should the axios request only happen once?

Comment: I want to run the effect initialy to populate the state(todos), and then evry time changes occur in the todos. I see what you mean, that I update setTodos and then put todos as dependency and it keeps looping like that. That means I have to define a new variable and set it as useEffect dependency and have that new piece of state beiing updated every time I make a change to todos. Idk. I'll give this a try.

Comment: It is running infinitely cos the useEffect runs every time the todos changes and the useEffect also changes the todos which makes it to run itself again and again. NB: To avoid infinite loops with useEffect, the useEffect must not change/mutate its dependency.

Answer (score 1):

You said that you need to fetch `todos` at first, and whenever `todos` change. I can suggest you a different approach, using one more variable, something like this:

```
const TodosComponent = (props) => {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [updatedTodos, setUpdatesTodos] = useState(true);

    const fetchFunction = () => {
        // In here you implement your fetch, in which you call setTodos().
    }

    // Called on mount to fetch your todos.
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchFunction();
    }, []);

    // Used to updated todos when they have been updated.
    useEffect(() => {
        if (updatedTodos) {
            fetchFunction();
            setUpdatesTodos(false);
        }
    }, [updatedTodos]);

    // Finally, wherever you update your todos, you also write `updateTodos(true)`. 
}
```